# How to set Last-Modified date of HTTP head via shell script

Tags: sh

I want to set the last modified date of a file on a remote HTTP server to a shell script variable.

```
CATEGORIES_DATE=$(date -d "$(curl -s -I -u ${URL} | grep Last-Modified | SOMETHING HERE)" +%Y-%m-%d)
```

The server is responding with: `Last-Modified: Sat, 28 Jul 2012 09:15:30 GMT` and I want to have `CATEGORIES_DATE=2012-07-28` in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk + date:

```
CATEGORIES_DATE="$(curl -s -I "${URL}" | awk '/^Last-Modified:/ { DATE=$3 " " $4 " " $5 ; system( "date -d \""  DATE "\" \"+%Y-%m-%d\"" ) }' )"
```

Awk will extract the required fields and feed them to date.